# What is the chronology of the Gundam series?

Tags: anime, suggested-order, chronological-order, mobile-suit-gundam

There are, roughly speaking, a zillion series under the umbrella of *Mobile Suit Gundam*. I personally loved *Gundam Wing* but I do know that it exists in an alternate timeline from the rest of the series.

What is the chronology of the Gundam series? Is there a specific order in which they are best watched? How many alternate timelines are there? Are there multiple series in these timelines?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Fortunately, many of the Gundams are easy to place in an in-universe chronological order, as the first entry in the franchise established the in-universe *Universal Century* (UC) calendar.  Most of the shared-universe Gundams take place in the Universal Century chronolgy, and for those specific shows they always establish what year they take place in. I'll be doing the in-universe UC year, then the year of release.

### Universal Century

| UC Year | Release Year | Series Name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| UC0079 | 1979 | *Mobile Suit Gundam* (the original series that started the franchise) |
| UC0079 | 1989 | *Mobile Suit Gundam 0080: War in the Pocket* |
| UC0079 | 1996 | *Mobile Suit Gundam: The 08th MS Team* |
| UC0079 | 2004 | *Mobile Suit Gundam MS IGLOO: The Hidden One Year War* |
| UC0079 | 2006 | *Mobile Suit Gundam MS IGLOO: Apocalypse 0079* |
| UC0079 | 2009 | *Mobile Suit Gundam MS IGLOO 2: The Gravity Front* |
| UC0079 | 2015 | *Mobile Suit Gundam: The Origin* (Manga/OVA) |
| UC0079 | 2019 | *Mobile Suit Gundam: The Origin – Advent of the Red Comet* (OVA-based TV Series) |
| UC0083 | 1991 | *Mobile Suit Gundam 0083: Stardust Memory* |
| UC0087 | 1985 | *Mobile Suit Zeta Gundam* (some compilation movies were released in 2005) |
| UC0087 | 2001 | *Gundam Neo Experience 0087: Green Divers* |
| UC0088 | 1986 | *Mobile Suit Gundam ZZ* |
| UC0093 | 1988 | *Mobile Suit Gundam: Char's Counterattack* |
| UC0096 | 2010 | *Mobile Suit Gundam Unicorn* |
| UC0123 | 1991 | *Mobile Suit Gundam F91* |
| UC0153 | 1993 | *Mobile Suit Victory Gundam* |

In terms of viewing order, most are pretty standalone. If you have the stomach for old-school anime, I'd recommend starting with the original *Mobile Suit Gundam*, as that will get you thoroughly familiar with key events in the universe.  The year UC0079 is a busy time as there's a wide-spread war taking place, which is why so many series take place roughly simultaneously then.  After watching the original, I'd recommend you read quick summaries of the other series, and try to watch ones that interest you.  *Char's Counterattack* is a notable non-standalone story that directly comes from the people and events of the original *Mobile Suit Gundam*.

> **Editor's note**: *MSG: The Origin* (recently released), while taking place chronologically before the original MSG series, contains several key spoilers for the MSG series and may not make as much sense without seeing MSG first

The rest of the series below take place in different universes than the above titles.  Many are one-off series/OVAs.  These are in no particular order.  The header is the calendar system the series takes place in, which is another way the makers of Gundam make it clear these are in different universes.

### Anno Domini

(Yes, these take place in our real-world timeline)

1. 2010

   - 2010 *Model Suit Gunpla Builders Beginning G* (I don't think this one is sharing much with the rest in this list, as it takes place 'in the present' in a world where Gundam is a fictional franchise)
2. 2307-2312

   - 2007 *Mobile Suit Gundam 00*
3. 2314

   - 2010 *Mobile Suit Gundam 00 the Movie: Awakening of the Trailblazer*

### After Colony

1. AC195

   - 1995 *Mobile Suit Gundam Wing*
2. AC196

   - 1997 *Gundam Wing: Endless Waltz*

### Advanced Generation

1. AG115, AG140

   - 2011-(ongoing) *Mobile Suit Gundam AGE*

### After War

1. AW0015

   - 1996 *After War Gundam X*

### Correct Century

1. CC2345

   - 1999 *∀ Gundam* (pronounced *Turn-A Gundam*)

### Cosmic Era

Gundam SEED was a recent extremely popular Gundam series.  It pulls elements from past Gundams and shares some similarities as a result.  I'd recommend this as an alternative to watching the original Mobile Suit Gundam.

1. CE71

   - 2002 *Mobile Suit Gundam SEED*
2. CE73

   - 2004 *Mobile Suit Gundam SEED Destiny*
   - 2006 *Mobile Suit Gundam SEED C.E. 73: Stargazer*

### Future Century

1. FC60

   - 1994 *Mobile Fighter G Gundam*

### Post Disaster

1. PD341

   - 2015 *Mobile Suit Gundam: Iron-Blooded Orphans*

An alternative way to get into Gundam is to watch a few of these side universe shows.  They share thematic similarities with the UC Gundams, but don't have as much history due to the lack of a shared continuity.

This list is not exhaustive, there are other series, and of course new Gundam works are still being produced.  Most of this information I gathered from [this Wikipedia list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gundam#Animated_series_and_films) which also has links to plot summaries and more information on all these and more.

Comment: Small note: Turn-A is widely espoused as tying together *all* the timelines that existed at the time it was produced. It is almost certainly a distant U.C. future series, given the historical records we see. Also, I think most series in U.C. tend to be much harder to watch out of chronological order, with the exception of Victory. Certainly, you're going to have a hard time understanding what in the heck is going on if you don't have some understanding of the history for Unicorn and before.

Comment: Some fans would argue that the release of the Z Gundam movie trilogy made ZZ Gundam and maybe also Char's Counterattack non-canon. Though I guess Bandai might claim they were just "offering another take" as well as looking for some commercial gains of course. Anyways Char's Counterattack seems to be canon no matter what, though the same cannot be said for ZZ, which was a bit controversial at the time of its release as well.

Answer (score 5):

I'm going to focus on the Universal Century universe since that is the most extensive and confusing of the Gundam arcs. The other answer explains all the different timelines that have been created so they can tell different stories with Gundams in different continuities. These series are all in the same universe with the One Year War, which happened in UC 0079. Any series with a (*) by the UC year happens within that war (i.e. parallel with the original MSG).

There are some [OVA series](https://epicstream.com/news/MadalenaDaleziou/What-Are-OVAs-in-Anime-and-How-Are-They-Different-Than-Specials-The-Meaning-and-Purpose-of-Original-Video-Animation-Explained) that were turned into full series. They overlap on content, but both are based on the original manga.

I excluded any short series with less than three episodes, as well as [non-serious works](https://gundam.fandom.com/wiki/Mobile_Suit_Gundam-san).

If you are wanting the MSG experience, be aware that *The Origin* contains massive spoilers about

> the motivations of Char Aznable (the titular "Red Comet"), as well as the other elements that lead up to the start of the One Year War. Char remains a mystery for most of the original MSG series.

There are several "Compilation Movies" that cover their respective series (Netflix has the three MSG movies currently but not the series).

This list is in chronological order, as opposed to the order of release. Series where the dates in the timeline are unclear are simply sub-ordered by release date.

| UC Year | Release Year | Series Name | Type |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| UC68-79 | 2015 | *Mobile Suit Gundam: The Origin* | OVA |
| UC68-79 | 2019 | *Mobile Suit Gundam: The Origin – Advent of the Red Comet* | Series |
| UC0079* | 1979 | ***Mobile Suit Gundam*** | Series |
| UC0079* | 1981 | *Mobile Suit Gundam I* (aka *Mobile Suit Gundam: The Movie*) | Compilation Movie |
| UC0079* | 1981 | *Mobile Suit Gundam II: Soldiers of Sorrow* | Compilation Movie |
| UC0079* | 1982 | *Mobile Suit Gundam III: Encounters in Space* | Compilation Movie |
| UC0079* | 1989 | *Mobile Suit Gundam 0080: War in the Pocket* | Series |
| UC0079* | 1996 | *Mobile Suit Gundam: The 08th MS Team* | Series |
| UC0079* | 2004 | *Mobile Suit Gundam MS IGLOO: The Hidden One Year War* | Series |
| UC0079* | 2006 | *Mobile Suit Gundam MS IGLOO: Apocalypse 0079* | Series |
| UC0079* | 2009 | *Mobile Suit Gundam MS IGLOO 2: The Gravity Front* | Series |
| UC0079* | 2015 | *Mobile Suit Gundam Thunderbolt* | Series |
| UC0079* | 2016 | *Mobile Suit Gundam Thunderbolt: December Sky* | Compilation Movie |
| UC0079* | 2017 | *Mobile Suit Gundam Thunderbolt: Bandit Flower* | Compilation Movie |
| UC0083 | 1991 | *Mobile Suit Gundam 0083: Stardust Memory* | Series |
| UC0083 | 1992 | *Mobile Suit Gundam 0083: The Afterglow of Zeon* | Compilation Movie |
| UC0083 | 2016 | *Mobile Suit Gundam 0083: Mayfly of Space 2* | Series |
| UC0087 | 1985 | *Mobile Suit Zeta Gundam* | Series |
| UC0087 | 2005 | *Mobile Suit Zeta Gundam: A New Translation - Heir to the Stars* | Compilation Movie |
| UC0087 | 2005 | *Mobile Suit Zeta Gundam: A New Translation II - Lovers* | Compilation Movie |
| UC0087 | 2006 | *Mobile Suit Zeta Gundam: A New Translation III - Love Is the Pulse of the Stars* | Compilation Movie |
| UC0088 | 1986 | *Mobile Suit Gundam ZZ* | Series |
| UC0093 | 1988 | *Mobile Suit Gundam: Char's Counterattack* | Movie |
| UC0096 | 2010 | *Mobile Suit Gundam Unicorn* | OVA |
| UC0096 | 2016 | *Mobile Suit Gundam Unicorn RE:0096* | Series |
| UC0096 | 2017 | *Mobile Suit Gundam Twilight Axis* | Series |
| UC0096 | 2017 | *Mobile Suit Gundam Twilight Axis - Red Trace* | Compilation Movie |
| UC0097 | 2018 | *Mobile Suit Gundam Narrative* | Movie |
| UC0105 | 2021 | *Mobile Suit Gundam Hathaway* | Movie |
| UC0123 | 1991 | *Mobile Suit Gundam F91* | Movie |
| UC0153 | 1993 | *Mobile Suit Victory Gundam* | Series |
| UC0223 | 1999 | *G-Saviour* (Canadian, live action) | Movie |